# NaN values in pivot_table index causes loss of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Here is a simple DataFrame:

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
                     'b': ['optional1', None, 'optional3'],
                     'c': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'],
                     'd': [1, 2, 3]})
> df

    a          b   c  d
0  a1  optional1  c1  1
1  a2       None  c2  2
2  a3  optional3  c3  3
```

#### Pivot method 1

The data can be pivoted to this:

```
> df.pivot_table(index=['a','b'], columns='c')
                d     
c              c1   c3
a  b                  
a1 optional1  1.0  NaN
a3 optional3  NaN  3.0
```

Downside: data in the 2nd row is lost because `df['b'][1] == None`.

#### Pivot method 2

```
> df.pivot_table(index=['a'], columns='c')
      d          
c    c1   c2   c3
a                
a1  1.0  NaN  NaN
a2  NaN  2.0  NaN
a3  NaN  NaN  3.0
```

Downside: column `b` is lost.

How can the two methods be combined so that columns `b` and the 2nd row are kept like so:

```
                d     
c              c1   c2   c3
a  b                  
a1 optional1  1.0  NaN  NaN
a2      None  NaN  2.0  NaN
a3 optional3  NaN  NaN  3.0
```

**More generally**: How can information from a row be retained during pivoting if a key has `NaN` value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `set_index` and `unstack` to perform the pivot:

```
df = df.set_index(['a', 'b', 'c']).unstack('c')
```

This is essentially what pandas does [under the hood](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape.py#L323) for `pivot`.  The `stack` and `unstack` methods are closely related to `pivot`, and can generally be used to perform pivot-like operations that don't quite conform with the built-in pivot functions.

The resulting output:

```
                d          
c              c1   c2   c3
a  b                       
a1 optional1  1.0  NaN  NaN
a2 NaN        NaN  2.0  NaN
a3 optional3  NaN  NaN  3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `fillna` to replace the `None` entry:

```
df['b'] = df['b'].fillna('foo')
df.pivot_table(index=['a','b'], columns=['c'])
----
                    d          
c              c1   c2   c3
a  b                       
a1 optional1  1.0  NaN  NaN
a2 foo        NaN  2.0  NaN
a3 optional3  NaN  NaN  3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
def pivot_table(df, index, columns, values):
    df = df[index + columns + values]
    i  = len(index)
    df = df.set_index(index+columns).unstack(columns).reset_index()
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)[:i].append(df.columns.droplevel(0)[i:])
    return df

pivot_table(df, index =['a', 'b'], columns= ['c'], values= ['d'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fillna` to replace type `None` to string `"NULL"`

Say...

```
df.fillna("NULL").pivot_table(index=['a'], columns='c')
```