# Pandas pivot_table incorrectly showing NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table, data-analysis

The following is the original structure of my data (pre-pivot):

```
    product    reviewer    rating
0       foo       userA        81
1       bar       userB        96
2       foo       userB        75
3       xyz       userA        42
```

I'm then running:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index="product", columns="reviewer", values="rating")
```

Which produces a new dataframe, laid out correctly, but mysteriously showing a lot more NaNs than belong:

```
       userA    userB
foo      NaN       75
bar      NaN       96
xyz      NaN      NaN
```

What's interesting is if I look at **df['userA']**:

```
product
      NaN
foo    81
bar    96
xyz   NaN
```

...which contains the correct data (although I'm not quite sure what's up with the blank row at the top, but that's not my concern).

---

Any idea what could be causing the extra NaNs to show up when displaying (or writing to csv) the full table even though all the values show up correctly when looking at a single column?

I've tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41839402/nan-values-in-pivot-table-index-causes-loss-of-data) by doing

```
df.set_index(['product', 'reviewer', 'rating']).unstack('reviewer')
```

but the result is the same (except now with "None" instead of "NaN").

Comment: Sorry about that, it's all 'id' in my data, but I changed it to product to make it more intuitive for this post, just missed a few occurrences.  Edited original post for consistency.

Comment: Your *edited* question is probably **no more a question**, because your *edited* command for creating your pivot table from your *edited* original data **now works correctly**.

Comment: All I did was edit it to accurately reflect what's happening in my code that was causing the error.  I'm not doing anything differently than before I wrote the post. 
 The dataframe post-pivot is showing NaN in some of the cases where there should be a rating value.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your data, you can do:

```
df_new=pd.pivot_table(df, index="product", columns="reviewer", values="rating").rename_axis(None,1)
print(df_new)

         userA  userB
product              
bar        NaN   96.0
foo       81.0   75.0
xyz       42.0    NaN
```

The blank id you referred can be removed by calling `rename_axis(None,1)`

Comment: I'm not actually so concerned about that blank index, that was more just something I noticed along the way.